# Como realizar una consulta entre dos rangos de fechas y un registro de otra columna MySQL

Tags: mysql, c#

Tengo una duda de como realizar una consulta entre un rango de fechas y un dato adicional de otra columna, lo que quiero ver es todos los registros de un numero de empleado entre el rango de fechas establecido,
Esta es mi tabla:

```
ID-no_empleado-nombre-ac_fijo_lap-ac_fijo_cel-fecha-registro
          
82  245863  JESUA BARRIENTOS    APD-0002    APD-0008    2023-01-12 18:18:49 Entrada
83  245863  JESUA BARRIENTOS        APD-0008    2023-01-13 02:50:39 Entrada
84  245863  JESUA BARRIENTOS    APD-0002    APD-0008    2023-01-14 08:26:26 Entrada
85  245863  JESUA BARRIENTOS    APD-0002    APD-0008    2023-01-14 08:26:31 Salida
86  245863  JESUA BARRIENTOS            2023-01-14 12:53:59 Entrada
87  245863  JESUA BARRIENTOS    APD-0002    APD-0008    2023-01-14 12:56:03 Salida
88  228932  IVAN MARTINEZ           2023-01-14 17:31:24 Entrada
89  228932  IVAN MARTINEZ           2023-01-14 17:31:29 Entrada
90  246921  MAYRA LOPEZ         2023-01-14 17:31:44 Entrada
91  245863  JESUA BARRIENTOS    APD-0002    APD-0008    2023-01-14 17:32:20 Salida
92  245863  JESUA BARRIENTOS            2023-01-14 17:40:21 Entrada
93  245863  JESUA BARRIENTOS    APD-0002    APD-0008    2023-01-17 10:41:19 Entrada
```

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
"SELECT * FROM registro_into WHERE (fecha BETWEEN '" + txt_finicial.Text + "' AND '" + txt_ffinal.Text + "') AND (no_empleado='" + txt_num_enmpleado.Text + "')"
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y cual es el problema???

Comment: Puedes utilizar un INNER JOIN a la otra tabla, Un ejemplo seria SELECT * FROM TABLA1 INNER JOIN TABLA 2 ON TABLA1.DatoEnComun = Tabla2.DatoEnComun

Comment: Debes formular mejor tu pregunta, pero con lo que veo en lo que compartiste. Deberías usar un DateTimePicker si usas Windows Form para las fechas no un TextBox. Cuando haces consulta en SQL el formato de fecha para consulta debe ser 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' para que pueda convertir el motor el texto en fecha y por ultimo si tu no_empleado empleado es numero no debes encerar entre comillas simples el valor si es varchar está correcto como lo tienes. Prueba haciendo esta consulta directamente en el motor. `"SELECT * FROM registro_into WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2023-01-13 00:00' AND '2023-01-14 17:32')"`

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes mapeado el modelo de datos, podrías hacer una consulta Linq:

```
using (ModeloBaseDatos db = new ModeloBaseDatos())
        {
            var lista = db.registro_into.Where(x => x.fecha >= txt_finicial && x.fecha <= txt_ffinal && x.no_empleado == txt_num_enmpleado).ToList();
        }
```